# iOS: How can I rotate a view control when another view segues to it?

Tags: iphone, xcode, rotation, autorotate

I'm making a app just for fun and it seems to be working fine except for the fact that when I want it to only be landscape on one screen, it will stay portrait. How can I make it so that it will automatically rotate to landscape when it loads?
I already tried this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);   
}
```

However this did not seem to work. Only when I rotate the device does it rotate the view and then it will stay in landscape but I want it to be able to do as soon as it loads without the user having to rotate their device to get it out of portrait. Is there anything that I'm missing? Thanks for all you help! If you would like more code from the app I would be more than happy to share it with you.

Answer (score 3):

Add this in viewDidLoad method and in shouldautorotate method:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
 [[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
 [[self view] setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
 [[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@interface UIViewController(ESUtils)
    -(void)changeToPortrait;
@end

@implementation UIViewController(ESUtils)
-(void)changeToPortrait
{
    //for will call a shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation func
    UIViewController *view = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:view animated:NO];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [view release];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do 2 things,

First on the interface builder, go to the view you want in land scape and make sure that the orientation is set to Landscape (if its in inferred it will take the parents orientation). You can find that under Simulated metrics on the 4th tab of the property inspector.

Now second, that view must have the code you posted

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);   
}
```